# Couchdb `Error: EXIT` error when using coffeescript functions

Tags: coffeescript, couchdb

I'm getting error that looks like that, whenever any design document function is called

```
    Error: EXIT

    {{badmatch,[]},
     [{couch_query_servers,new_process,3,
                           [{file,"/tmp/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_query_servers.erl"},
                            {line,472}]},
      {couch_query_servers,lang_proc,3,
                           [{file,"/tmp/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_query_servers.erl"},
                            {line,462}]},
      {couch_query_servers,handle_call,3,
                           [{file,"/tmp/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_query_servers.erl"},
                            {line,322}]},
      {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,588}]},
      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was because i had misspelled `language` property in my `_design/document`.

```
{
   "_id": "_design/myapp",
   "_rev": "20-cafeb7b6886a37e8c629978f934eea86",
   "language": "cofeescript", // <- Notice misspelled tag
   "lists": {
   },
   "shows": {
   },
   "validate": "...",
   "validate_doc_update": "...",
   "views": {   },
   "couchapp": { ... }
}
```